# porque me sale este error? [Error] ld returned 1 exit status en C

Tags: c

Me salio este error una vez porque tenia una ventana abierta, pero en este caso no encuentro ninguna ventana, ya le cambié el nombre, lo cerre y lo volvi abrir y hasta lo guarde en otro lugar y nada.
El programa es de estructuras con punteros, gracias

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct personas{
    char nombre[30];
    int edad;
}persona,*p_persona=&persona;

void datos();
void m(personas *);

int main(){

datos();
m(p_persona);

return 0;
}

void datos(){
    printf("nombre: ");
    scanf("%s",p_persona->nombre,30,'\n');
    printf("edad: ");
    scanf("%i",p_persona->edad);
}

void m(){
    printf("\nEl nombre es: %s",p_persona->nombre );
    printf("\nLa edad es: ",p_persona->edad);

}
```

Comment: Una sería la declaración `void m(personas *);` tiene un argumento, pero al definirla lo pones sin argumentos, declaración y definición deberían coincidir, a menos que trates de sobrecargar la función en cuyo caso la función `m` con argumento no estaría definida.

Comment: si era eso, gracias

Answer (score 2):

La declaración y la definición de `m` no coinciden, entonces, o quitas el argumento de la declaración o le aumentas el argumento en la definición, en tu caso me parece que deberías quitar el argumento, tanto en la declaración como en la llamada dentro del `main`.

Los argumentos de `scanf` deben pasarse por referencia, es decir, anteponiendo `&` a la variable donde queremos almacenar la entrada, al tratarse de un `array` de tipo `char`, el `&` se omite (ver la [sintaxis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf#Sintaxis)).

Entonces el código quedaría así:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct personas {
    char nombre[30];
    int edad;
}persona, *p_persona = &persona;

void datos();
void m();

int main() {

    datos();
    m();

    return 0;
}

void datos() {
    printf("nombre: ");
    scanf("%30s", p_persona->nombre);
    printf("edad: ");
    scanf("%i", &(p_persona->edad));
}

void m() {
    printf("\nEl nombre es: %s", p_persona->nombre);
    printf("\nLa edad es: %i", p_persona->edad);
}
```

Comment: ya no me aparece ese error pero otro error que igual tenia es que no me imprime nuevamente los datos que el usario pone, saben porque ?

Comment: Cambiaste el código a como lo describo y ¿aún te sale el error?

Comment: Esta línea de código: `scanf("%s", p_persona->nombre, 30, '\n');` sigue estando mal. Si el usuario escribe más de 30 caracteres habrá buffer overflow. La forma correcta sería: `scanf("%30s", p_persona->nombre);`.

Comment: Gracias por apuntar ése detalle @MrDave1999, lo editaré.