# ¿Por qué no me imprime los datos del usuario?

Tags: c, usercontrol

Este es mi código, copila y todo pero al momento en que el usario pone sus datos al final no lo imprime y no sé porqué. Creo que no entra a la siguente función de imprimir.:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    struct personas{
    char nombre[30];
    int edad;
}persona,*p_persona=&persona;

void datos();
void m(personas *);

int main(){

    datos();
    m(p_persona);

    return 0;
}

void datos(){
    printf("nombre: ");
    scanf("%s",p_persona->nombre,30,'\n');
    printf("edad: ");
    scanf("%i",p_persona->edad);
}

void m(personas *p_persona){
    printf("\nEl nombre es: %s",p_persona->nombre );
    printf("\nLa edad es: ",p_persona->edad);

}
```

Es un programa de estructuras con punteros, apenas estoy aprendiendo estos temas, gracias.

Comment: duplicado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332034/porque-me-sale-este-error-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status-en-c .

Answer (score 1):

Es bueno que sigas aprendiendo :)

Ahora, el problema del código reside en este simple carácter "&".

```
scanf("%i",p_persona->edad);
```

Esa es tu variable, pero recuerda que estas tratando con "int".

Así que para que el scanf es necesario utilzar "&" antes del nombre de la variable. 
Quedando de esta manera.

```
scanf("%i",&p_persona->edad);
```

Esa seria la solución al problema que estas teniendo.

No olvides en esta parte

```
printf("\nLa edad es: ",p_persona->edad);
```

Llamar a la variable usando %d antes de cerrar las comillas.

Suerte!

Comment: muchas gracias!